# gulp-favicons not working as part of gulp workflow

Tags: npm, gulp

I installed gulp-favicons as part of my gulp workflow but it crashes when this I use `favicons = require('gulp-favicon');` even without running the task, it still produces the following error:

```
/Volumes/SK Repo 1.0/Projects/Stalin Kay/Web Development/htdocs/namcor/mockup/node_modules/gulp-favicons/index.js:3
(() => {
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/SK Repo 1.0/Projects/Stalin Kay/Web Development/htdocs/namcor/mockup/gulpfile.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Node.js version is too old. `favicons` uses [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) through out its [code](https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons/blob/master/index.js). Arrow functions have only been available since Node.js 4.x.

The requirement is even mentioned in the `favicons` [README](https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons#favicons-):

> A Node.js module for generating favicons and their associated files. Originally built for Google's Web Starter Kit and Catalyst. **Requires Node 4+.**

Comment: Thanks, I actually hadn't double-checked my dependencies.